# Adding a security layer for a url based QRCode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created an app for generating a QRCode in which we can give url as its input. And now i would like to incorporate a security layer for that url. That is, while scanning that url it should not redirect directly to that specified url, instead a password authentication should be performed before redirecting.

I like to generate an application which produces an output as shown here http://www.myqr.co. So can anyone explain how to do that?

Comment: Any security needs to be on the website hosting the URL. If someone scans your QRCode, they simply get a string from the encoded data. There is no security. If the string happens to be a URL, the user can go to the URL. There is no way to protect the QRCode at that level.

Comment: @maddy did you visit the link i provided.You said that we cannot provide any security. Then can you explain how it is done?

Comment: That's a feature specific to that website. The generated QR code takes you to their website and then redirects you to the actual website. If a password was entered by the creator, then the user is prompted for the password. In other words, the QR code is not encoded with the final URL. It is encoded with an intermediate URL for myqr.co. Your app would need to do the same. You would need to setup a server to handle everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot provide any security code inside QR Code algorithm.The only thing you can do is add such security feature inside your website and make your website redirect the user to the required url.